# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _gfortran_internal_malloc64

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit

Ubuntu 13.04 here.

I was trying to use a program called `smartpca` and the first time I tried to use it, it raised a dependency error about a `liblapack`.

I installed libatlas3-base and it was solved. Then it raised another error about `libgfortran.so.1`. Since I had all `libfortran` packages installed, i created a link between `libgfortran.so.3` and `libgfortran.so.1`.

Then I ran the program again and it raised that error:

```
./smartpca: symbol lookup error: ./smartpca: undefined symbol: _gfortran_internal_malloc64
```

From what I read, I understand that on Fedora you have to install `gfortran 4.1`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Areyou sure its Fedora?

Comment: What I meant was that I saw only one solution on the web, and it was on Fedora (to be specific, the package compat-libgfortran-41-4.1.2-36.x86_64). On ubuntu, there is no such package (at least from what I have tried to find).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. I needed to make EIGENSOFT from the source code. This helped:

> This is one way that eigensoft has been installed
>   on a Ubuntu computer.
>
> First install the dependencies:
>   gfortran
>   liblapack-dev
>
> Now cd to the src directory and build as follows:
>   $ make all
>   $ make install
>
> At this point you should have some files in the eigensoft/bin directory.
>   Note that the installation does not require admin privileges
>   and does not put files anywhere outside of the eigensoft directory tree.
>
> To uninstall, cd to the src directory and run:
>   $ make clobber
>
> To check that eigensoft has reverted to the pre-installed state,
>   check git status if eigensoft has been cloned from a git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for Matlab R2012a, Ubuntu 13.04

Error:

> libgfortran.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  /MATLAB/share/libfst.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_internal_malloc64

Solution:

1. Go to: http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/linux.html
2. Download **libgfortran patch for 64-bit Linux (x86_64)**: http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/software/lheasoft/release/updates/heasoft6.14-libgfortran-pc-linux64.tar.gz
3. Untar and copy files to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
4. Enjoy!